# What design pattern should to affect a specific object with an ActionListener

Tags: java, design-patterns, actionlistener

I got two `JButton` that implements the same `ActionListener`.

This `ActionListener` need to call a function on my other object which i will call **container** just for the sake of this question.

Because two classes uses `ActionListener` I made it a outer-class.

Just to give a context, **button1** is a `JMenuItem` and **button2** is a JButton on a `JToolBar` uses my `ActionListener` and are not directly linked to **container**. **container** is a `JPanel` in a `JPanel` in a `Jpanel`.

I thought to register **container** to my `ActionListener`, just like i would do with an *Observer pattern* and keep an `ArrayList` containing, but i'm not sure if it is the good approach.

I've read about the *Visitor pattern*, but honestly i don't quite see the difference with the *Observer pattern*.

What i understand from a *Bridge pattern* is that i decouple the object so two distinct object can evolve indepently from each other.

Is there another approach I did'nt explore that would be better?

I find the issue confusing so my question is probably confusing as well. Let me know if you need more specificity.

**-------------EDIT----------------------**

```
public class Main {

static MyFrame f;

public static void main(String[] args) {

     f = new MyFrame();
     f.setVisible(true);
}

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public Frame() {
        this.setSize(200, 200);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(new PaneOne(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(new PaneTwo(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.add(new Container(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

public class PaneOne extends JPanel {

    JButton button1 = new JButton("One");

    public PaneOne() {
        button1.addActionListener(new Action());
        this.add(button1);
    }
}

public class PaneTwo extends JPanel {

    JButton button2 = new JButton("two");

    public PaneTwo() {
        button2.addActionListener(new Action());
        this.add(button2);
    }
}

public class Container extends JPanel {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Before");
    public Container() {
        this.add(label);
    }
}

public class Action implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //I want to change the content of label in Container
        //I really got no clue on how to do it

    }

}
}
```

Here is a **VERY VERY VERY** simplified example. My code got more "depthness" in it. My **Container** is more deeper so a direct reference would be to complicated.

I might be over-engeneering this, but i got no clue on how to link those classes together.

My first solution was to make my `ActionListener` as a *Singleton* and link it like I would do with a *Observer pattern*.

**------------------EDIT2-------------------**
This code look a bit more like my actual design. The `ActionListener` is a *Singleton* and need my **container** to register to it.

Sorry for the confusion, but this issue really make me wonder how things work.

```
public class Main {

static MyFrame f;

public static void main(String[] args) {

     f = new MyFrame();
     f.setVisible(true);
}

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {
        this.setSize(200, 200);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(new PaneOne(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(new PaneTwo(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.add(new Container(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

public class PaneOne extends JPanel {

    JButton button1 = new JButton("One");

    public PaneOne() {
        button1.addActionListener(Action.getInstance());
        this.add(button1);
    }
}

public class PaneTwo extends JPanel {

    JButton button2 = new JButton("two");

    public PaneTwo() {
        button2.addActionListener(Action.getInstance());
        this.add(button2);
    }
}

public class Container extends JPanel implements Observer {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Before");
    Action action = Action.getInstance(); 
    public Container() {
        action.register(this);
        this.add(label);
    }
}

public class Action implements ActionListener {

    Container observer;

    static Action action;

    protected Action() {

    }

    public static Action getInstance() {
        if(action == null) {
            action = new Action();
        }
        return action;
    }

    public void register(Observer o) {
        observer = o;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        observer.label.setText("After");

    }

}

public interface Observer {
    public void update();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please update your question with some code that reflects your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @BranislavLazic: a concrete [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help clarify a **lot** of ambiguity.

Comment: Good. I almost wonder if you might be over-engineering this, if instead you might be better off with a little more simplicity.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Edit posted. I might be, I want to know if instead of using a *Singleton* and register **container** to it, if there is another solution, a more correct way of doing it. You know, standards.

Comment: I would use an MCV pattern myself. Answer forthcoming.

Comment: I already use an MCV pattern both of my panel have a controller(but no model, it was not necessary)

Comment: But the model is important, and probably most important.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels How come? What I know from a model is that it keep information in the back or do processing like adding in a calculator.

Comment: Because that is what truly lets you uncouple your logic from your GUI, what truly reduces your cyclomatic complexity, and that's your main goal in all of this.

Comment: I know for instance that the view is the one that get the user input, the model is the one doing all the process, the calculation... and finally the controller is like the conductor of an orchestra. So far the only action my program do is via the `ActionListener`. Why would i need a model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72377/discussion-between-chax-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, I recommend that you use an MVC approach, where you try to create a "dumb" view, one that knows how to get information, to set information but is ignorant of connections and of logic, and rather having that code elsewhere. For example, while the code below is a bit complex, it does allow complete separation of concerns. The view has no idea that its JTextField is connected to its JLabel or how the connection occurs. Rather the control and a listener to the model takes care of all of that.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

public class SortOfSimpleMvc {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SimpleView view = new SimpleView();
      SimpleModel model = new SimpleModel();
      new SimpleControl(model, view);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleMvc");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(view.getMainPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class SimpleView {
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 5));
   private TextFieldView textFieldView = new TextFieldView();
   private LabelView labelView = new LabelView();

   public SimpleView() {
      JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
      topPanel.add(textFieldView.getMainPanel());
      topPanel.add(labelView.getMainPanel());

      mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

   }

   public JComponent getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   public void setText(String text) {
      labelView.setLabelText(text);
   }

   public String getFieldText() {
      return textFieldView.getFieldText();
   }

   public void addAction(Action action) {
      buttonPanel.add(new JButton(action));

   }
}

class TextFieldView {
   private JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

   public TextFieldView() {
      mainPanel.add(field);
   }

   public JComponent getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   public String getFieldText() {
      return field.getText();
   }
}

class LabelView {
   private JLabel label = new JLabel("Before");
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

   public LabelView() {
      mainPanel.add(label);
   }

   public JComponent getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   public void setLabelText(String text) {
      label.setText(text);
   }
}

class SimpleModel {
   public static final String TEXT = "text";
   private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(
         this);
   private String text;

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
   }

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }

   public void setText(String text) {
      String oldValue = this.text;
      String newValue = text;
      this.text = text;
      pcSupport.firePropertyChange(TEXT, oldValue, newValue);
   }

}

class SimpleControl {

   private SimpleModel model;
   private SimpleView view;

   public SimpleControl(SimpleModel model, SimpleView view) {
      this.model = model;
      this.view = view;

      model.addPropertyChangeListener(SimpleModel.TEXT, new ModelListener());

      view.addAction(new ChangeAction("Change Text", KeyEvent.VK_C));
      view.addAction(new RemoveAction("Remove Text", KeyEvent.VK_R));
   }

   private class ChangeAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ChangeAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         String text = view.getFieldText();
         model.setText(text);
      }
   }

   private class RemoveAction extends AbstractAction {
      public RemoveAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         model.setText("");
      }
   }

   private class ModelListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
         view.setText(evt.getNewValue().toString());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your example is quite complex honestly, but it clarify some fact about MVC.

First, if i understand correctly, the view is not even aware how many `JButton` it has. 

Second, Let's say you had two view, two model and two controller, if the action take part in the first set, how do you notify the second set? I'm a bit baffled by the complexity of this example

Answer (score 0):

Chax -

`JButton` should not implement `ActionListener`, because the button is not the listener.
`JButton` inherits the method `addActionListener(ActionListener l)` from `AbstractButton`.  Create the `ActionListener` object separately and simply add the same `ActionListener` instance to the two `JButton` objects.

```
JButton jb1 = new MyJButton();
JButton jb2 = new MyOtherJButton();
ActionListener al = new MyActionListener();
jb1.addActionListener(al);
jb2.addActionListener(al);
```

Now, `ActionEvents` from both buttons will call the same `ActionListener`.  Inside of the `MyActionListener` class, you will implement the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` to make the call to **container**:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    container.methodCall();
}
```

This is the essence of the *observer design pattern*.  The `ActionListener` objects added to `JButton` are notified of the action in that `JButton`, and they can take the proper action.

Comment: my JButton does not implements `ActionListener`. I will post a second code edit. It does look a bit more like my actual design